# Как выложить сайт Laravel на хостинг?

Tags: laravel

При переносе сайта написанном на ларавеле версии 5.8 на хостинг отображается кодовое содержимое index.php. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, что что-то не так с вашей конфигурацией сервера, вот несколько вещей, которые вы можете проверить:

- Убедитесь, что PHP установлен и работает правильно. Это может показаться глупым, но вы никогда не знаете. Простой способ проверить - запустить php -v из командной строки и посмотреть, возвращает ли информация о версии или какие-либо ошибки.
- Убедитесь, что модуль PHP указан и раскомментирован внутри вашего Apache httpd.conf. Это должно быть что-то вроде LoadModule php5_module "c: /php/php5apache2_2.dll" в файле. Найдите LoadModule php и убедитесь, что перед ним нет комментария (;).
- Убедитесь, что в файле Apache httpd.conf есть PHP MIME-тип. Это должно быть что-то вроде AddType application/x-httpd-php.php.
- Убедитесь, что ваш файл имеет расширение .php на нем или любое расширение, указанное в определении MIME в пункте №3, иначе оно не будет выполняться как PHP.
- Убедитесь, что вы не используете короткие теги в файле PHP < ? Они не всегда включены на серверах по умолчанию.

Comment: При создании доменного имени не указал поддержку PHP. В этом и была причина.